Help identifying 10-pin SMD IC in TP-Link TL-SG2008P switch
I'm trying to identify a 10-pin SMD IC located on a TP-Link TL-SG2008P switch. The markings on the chip are:

First line: 2620
Second line: 2868

This IC is located near an MB510 diode and a Realtek RTL82ji chip on the board. I suspect it might be related to power management or signal conversion, as this switch supports PoE (Power over Ethernet). Unfortunately, I haven’t been able to find any official documentation or schematics to help identify this component.
Any experience with this switch model would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!



It's a SCT SCT2620 step-down converter.


(Source: lcsc.com)

This helps me a lot, thanks for your response!!!
